# Associative array key - Replacing space with double dashes

Tags: php, arrays

Please take a look at my array below -

```
        $data = Array(
            'categories' => Array(
                '64' => Array(
                    'subset' => Array
                    (
                        'Sub depot' => 0,
                        'Depot' => 0,
                        'Neutral' => 0,
                        'Agree' => 0,
                        'Total child' => 3,
                        'Not applicable' => 0,
                        'overall_staff' => 15,
                        'available_staff' => 15,
                        'staff_rate' => 100,
                    ),
                    'total_candidates' => 3,
                    'count_managers' => 3,
                    'name' => 'Role of the Board'
                ),

                '65' => Array
                (
                    'subset' => Array
                    (
                        'Sub depot' => 0,
                        'Depot' => 0,
                        'Neutral' => 1,
                        'Agree' => 1,
                        'Total child' => 0,
                        'Not applicable' => 0,
                        'overall_staff' => 7,
                        'available_staff' => 10,
                        'staff_rate' => 70,
                    ),
                    'total_candidates' => 2,
                    'count_managers' => 2,
                    'name' => 'The Chairman'
                )

            )
        );
```

There are some keys which have space e.g. "sub depot". I need to replace this space with double dashes "--" or "@@".

As this array is 4 level deep, I can't seem to get array_walk and array_walk_recursive. Are you able to help?

Comment: Do you need to do this replacement at all levels, or just level 4?

Comment: For this specfic set, level 4 required only but would be nice at any level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive function :

```
function replaceSpaces($data, $with) {

    if (!is_array($data)) return;

    $formatedArray = array();

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

        $formatedArray[str_replace(' ', $with, $key)] = is_array($value) ? replaceSpaces($value, $with) : $value;

    }

    return $formatedArray;
}

$newArray = replaceSpaces($data, '@@');
```

`array_walk_recursive` is not good for your case because you can only edit value with it.

Edit :
Working example here
https://implode.io/PaH0eP

Comment: Brilliant! it works as required. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use nested loops. When the key contains a space, create a new key, add that to the array, and remove the old key with `unset()`.

```
foreach ($data as &$level1) {
    foreach ($level1 as &$level2) {
        foreach ($level2 as &$level3) {
            if (is_array($level3)) {
                foreach ($level3 as $key => $value) {
                    if (strstr($key, " ")) {
                        $new_key = str_replace(" ", "--", $key);
                        unset($level3[$key]);
                        $level3[$new_key] = $value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's necessary to use reference variables so that the assignment will update the original array.

Comment: Thank you. I'm getting "Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" for this line "foreach ($level3 as $key => $value)" ... So I'd need to add more checks there.

Comment: Some of the level 3 values aren't nested arrays, I needed to check for that.

Comment: Yes, that's what I added too. Thanks for looking into this for me.